# Getting ModuleNotfoundError while trying to import the code from another python file from same directory in pycharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'videos_thumbnail_extraction'

Getting the above error while importing the 'videos_thumbnail_extraction.py' file code into another python file.

What I am doing is:

Importing videos_thumbnail_extraction.py to channel_stats.py then importing channel_stats.py to main.py, From main.py I am triggering the flask server.

[image]

Comment: (1) Show errors and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. (2) Show the full traceback of the error.(3) Show or describe where the files are located in the file system. (4) Show the actual code for importing the file. (5) Which is the main script with which you start the program (probably `main.py`)?

Answer (score 0):

Running your code as a module may help. Try using python -m main.py from the command line